# Read in 12-bit grayscale video in numpy array

Tags: python, grayscale, opencv

I'm trying to read in a 12-bit grayscale video 720×720
into an array like `arrayname[framecount,720,720,1]` where the last dimension varies from 0 to 2<sup>12</sup> since it's a 12-bit grayscale video.

This is what I did so far (based on another code from Stack Overflow from ivan_onys):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.avi") 
frCount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

print(frCount,frWidth,frHeight)


imgbuf = np.empty((frCount, frHeight, frWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8')) 
fc = 0
retVal = True
while (fc < frCount  and ret):
    retVal, imgbuf[fc] = cap.read()
    fc += 1

cap.release()
print(imgbuf.shape) #dim = frames, height, width, channels(bgr)
```

This reads my video like it's an RGB video but I want it grayscale and don't lose the information.

I read in the documentation, but it just tells me for `VideoCapture` this: `cv.VideoCapture(filename, apiPreference, params)`, where I don't really understand what `apiPreference` is and if there's a parameter suited for this I didnt see it.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer your question without having the AVI file (at least short part of the AVI file). It in possible but unlikely that the AVI contains 12 bits Grayscale data. And: as far as I know OpenCV supports only 8 bits videos.

Comment: Ok this is indeed pretty hard for me to share. I will have a more indepth research about OpenCV and see if its really just for 8bit Videos. I also worked with the RGB 8 bit data, that Open CV could give me and so far it worked for what I'm trying to do. Its also not to much of an issue if I have to use an other software. Thanks for the answer :)